# How much should I dig a hole to set a post?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, earth, elasticity

I need your help to solve this problem

We suppose that we have a post pulled by
$N=4$ barbed wires separated a distance $dh = 30 \text cm$, and that each wire pulls with a force of
$F=300\text   N$ . The question is how much should I bury the post $\text H$ for the post doesn't move.

What I tried was to suppose that below there are two uniform pressures that impede the post to move $f_a$ and $f_R$, and that the post has width $W$.

the force sum is

$$N F= (f_a-f_R) W H$$
and the moment sum with respect to ground is

$$-F(dh+ 2 dh+ 3 dh + ... + N dh) =  - \int_0^H (f_A -f_R) z W dz$$

$$-Fdh N(N+1)/2= -(f_A-f_R)H^2/2 W$$

Here my doubt is that the linear system is indeterminated but must fulfills the condition

$$F dh N(N+1)/2= N F/(WH) *H^2/2 W$$
therefore

$$dh (N+1)=  H$$

or

$$H= (N+1) dh$$

In such a case if I dig a hole of $5*30 cm = 1.5 m$, I can pull the post with any force and it will stand.
Physically I known that when no force is applied to the post, the pressure is symmetric and with value $\rho g z$, where $z$ is the depth. When I pulled with a force $F$, then we are compressing the ground by one side and by the other side maybe the pressure falls to zero if we imagine contact is lost. So it is possible that $f_A$ is very small. But as it maybe rotating, maybe the pressure falls and rises on both sides.  Can anybody help me?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you actually building a fence?  If so maybe check the [home improvement stack exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/226585/what-is-a-suitable-post-hole-depth-for-a-4-fence) or is this a homework problem in which case you should tag it as such.

Comment: Yes, I am building a fence, I need 300 m of barbed wire. Each wire withstand 4000 Newtons before breaking. I wanted to set the post with 4 or 5 wires each one at its maximum capacity. But the problem was how long should  the hole be.

Comment: This is a great question on the practical use of physics. Let's see if the mathematicians can provide a real world answer.